# react-native fetch().then() returning object Object

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, fetch, return-value

I am doing a network request very similar to the example code of react-native.

Networking.js

```
export default class Networking {

  static tryLogin() {

    return fetch('https://exampleserver.com')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });

  }
}
```

I'd like to retrieve responseJson and process it in another class, however, `.then((responseJson)` is returning objectObject instead of my JSON. I am calling this method using `Networking.tryLogin();`

When replacing `return responseJson` with `alert(responseJson)` it works as expected, so it has to be something with the returning.

Edit:
When doing console.log() I am getting:

```
 Promise {
   "_40": 0,
   "_55": null,
   "_65": 0,
   "_72": null,
}
```

Comment: Is it just that you're return object is too large for the console to show?

Comment: Please show how you are consuming the call to tryLogin

Comment: Where are you seeing objectObject returned? like on an alert? or are you using the React Native debugger to send it to the console?

Comment: I am calling the function and alerting it: `alert(Networking.tryLogin());`
I am seeing 'objectObject' in the alert box. But it is the same in console.log()

Comment: @spender please have a look at the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a Promise in `tryLogin()`. So you need to access its value in a `.then()` method:

```
Networking.tryLogin().then(response => console.log(response));
```

---

In addition to the question asked in comments, as explained in [react-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network):

> Networking is an inherently asynchronous operation. **Fetch methods will return a Promise** that makes it straightforward to
>   write code that works in an asynchronous manner.

Comment: I suggest that the OP goes back to the books to learn about how Promise works and especially about how `async` and `await` make life really easy when dealing with Promise.

Comment: Thank you. Why am I returning a promise when I already do have the .thens in the tryLogin() method? What would I need to do, to save the response to a variable in order to process it further?

Comment: @j.Doe please check the updated answer for your question. For saving response, simply just assign it to a variable that is defined outside `then()` method.

Comment: @MohammadrezaFarahani sure, but how do I check if the request has finished? Do I assign a standard value outside `then()` method and let a `while` loop wait until value has changed?

Comment: @j.Doe When the `then` block I mentioned in the answer is invoked, it means the request has finished. No need for other statements. For easier usage as spender suggested, you should use `async` and `await`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Promise.all()`.

I had a similar question as OP, and found [this article](https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/using-the-javascript-fetch-api-f92c756340f0). A bit old, but working! The main point is the following code:

```
const apiRequest1 = fetch('api.example1.com/search').then(function(response){ 
         return response.json()
});
const apiRequest2 = fetch('api.example2.com/search').then(function(response){
         return response.json()
});
const combinedData = {"apiRequest1":{},"apiRequest2:{}};
Promise.all([apiRequest1,apiRequest2]).then(function(values){
    combinedData["apiRequest1"] = values[0];
    combinedData["apiRequest2"] = values[1];
    return combinedData;
});
```